# Return the nth digit of a number

Tags: java, number-manipulation

```
public class Return {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        int answer = digit(9635, 1);
        print("The answer is " + answer);
    }

    static void print(String karen) {
        System.out.println (karen);
    }

    static int digit(int a, int b) {
        int digit = a;
        return digit;
    }     
}
```

Create a program that uses a function called **digit** which returns the value of the nth 
digit from the right of an integer argument. The value of n should be a second argument.

For Example: `digit(9635, 1)` returns `5` and `digit(9635, 3)` returns `6`.

Comment: Having any specific issue with the code? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Keep dividing by 10 a certain number of times, then take modulo 10 at the end. Is that enough to get you going with your homework?

Comment: what does digit(9635, 1) returns 5 means... what is the returns 5 is it from 9635?

Comment: I suggest that you read the description again: "Create a program that uses a function called digit which returns the value of the nth digit from the right of an integer argument." explains exactly where the `5` comes from.

Comment: Yes! @Code-Guru what i mean is what is returns 5 means... where does it come from.. I'm presently learning Java in our school...

Comment: In Java, "`digit(9635 ,1)` returns 5" means that the result of the `digits` function is 5 when the inputs are 9635 and 1. Do you understand *why* this is the result?

Comment: @Code-Guru can you please give me some examples how to code return based on my problem... so i can understand....

Comment: You can get the last digit by dividing by 10 and look at the remainder of the division. int lastDigit = a%10;

Comment: @Code-Guru no sir i really don't have any idea why... I'm a bit confused....

Comment: @Joey First, I suggest you make sure you know why the examples give the results that are stated. Then I suggest that you research how the `/` and `%` operators work. These are crucial to understanding how to write a very short function to get those results.

Comment: @Joey You also need to understand how numbers are represented in the decimal system that we use every day.

Comment: @Joey What is the 1st digit from the right of 9635? What is the 3rd digit from the right of 9635?

Comment: You can also think about this recursively.

Comment: When struggling for what to do, try writing what you know, even if it's just the statement of the problem or a definition of one of its words!

Comment: @Code-Guru: Am i going to divide or get a remainder from digits(9635, 1)? .. i just dont get why it says returns 5?

Comment: What is the 1st digit from the right of 9635?

Comment: @Code-Guru number 5... how can i show number 5 if the user inputs 1??

Comment: The user should input **both** numbers: 9635 and 1.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Without spoon-feeding you the code:

The nth digit is the remainder after dividing (`a` divided by 10<sup>b-1</sup>) by 10.

> `int digit(int a, int b) {`
>      `return a / (int)Math.pow(10, b - 1) % 10;`
>  `}`
>  See [live demo](https://ideone.com/9pc0tM).

---

If you want an iterative approach:

Loop b-1 times, each time assigning to the `a` variable the result of dividing `a` by 10.
After looping, the nth digit is the remainder of dividing `a` by 10.

> `int digit(int a, int b) {`
>      `while (--b > 0) {`
>          `a /= 10;`
>      `}`
>      `return a % 10;`
>  `}`
>  See [live demo](https://ideone.com/i6uO9X).

---

Relevant facts about Java:

- The modulo operator `%` returns the remainder after division, eg `32 % 10` returns  `2`
- Integer division drops remainders, eg `32 / 10` returns `3`.

Answer (score 2):

```
static int dig(int a, int b) {
    int i, digit=1;
    for(i=b-1; i>0; i++)
        digit = digit*10;
    digit = (a/digit) % 10;
    return digit;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The other way is convert the digit into array and return the nth index

```
static char digit(int a,int b)
    {
        String x=a+"";
        char x1[]=x.toCharArray();
        int length=x1.length;
        char result=x1[length-b];
        return result;
    }
```

Now run from your main method like this way

```
System.out.println("digit answer  "+digit(1254,3));
```

**output**

```
digit answer  2
```

Comment: @SpiderPig Maybe not fastest in real time, but that's the perfect computational theory answer

Comment: @SpiderPig Since the OP is struggling with terminology such as "returns", recursion is a less than helpful suggestion. (And I think I could code a direct calculation in less key strokes than I could do a recursive solution.)

Answer (score 0):

Convert number to string and then use the **charAt**() method.

```
class X{   
    static char digit(int a,int n)
    {
        String x=a+"";
        return x.charAt(n-1); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(X.digit(123, 2));
    }
}
```

You may want to double check that the nth position is within the length of the number:

```
static char digit(int a, int n) {
    String x = a + "";
    char digit='\0' ;
    if (n > 0 && n <= x.length()) {
        digit = x.charAt(n - 1);
    }
    return digit;
}
```