# Compute a randomly selected digit from a given four digit number

Tags: matlab

I need to compute a randomly selected digit from a given four digit number. In this question, I use the terminology similar to *“digit 3 of the number 7246 is 2”* and *“digit 1 of the number 7246 is 6”*. That is, digit numbers count from the right, starting at 1.

**Input variables:**

- `number` is a single four digit number.

**Output Variables:**

- `which_digit` holds a random integer between `1` and `4` using `randi`
- `digit` holds the `which_digit` digit of `number`.

A sample case is:

```
>> number = 7246;
>> rand_digit
which_digit = 3
digit = 2
```

Comment: What is your specific question/detail you need help implementing?

Comment: Hi user15156627, welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [ask] and [How to Ask Homework Questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)). We are not here to do your homework but we can help you to do it

Comment: This question appears to be narrowly scoped, and focused. I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate a random number in a certain range in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077800/generate-a-random-number-in-a-certain-range-in-matlab) followed by [Matlab: Is there a function to locate an 'n' digit in a number (i.e 2nd digit in '75673', so 5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26960213/matlab-is-there-a-function-to-locate-an-n-digit-in-a-number-i-e-2nd-digit-in)

Answer (score 0):

Combining the answers from:

- [Generate a random number in a certain range in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077800/generate-a-random-number-in-a-certain-range-in-matlab)
- [Matlab: Is there a function to locate an 'n' digit in a number (i.e 2nd digit in '75673', so 5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26960213/matlab-is-there-a-function-to-locate-an-n-digit-in-a-number-i-e-2nd-digit-in)

You could do something like:

```
function [which_digit, digit] = randDigit(number)
which_digit = randi([1, 4]);
digit = floor(mod(number, 10^which_digit) / 10^(which_digit-1));
end
```