# Find the n-th Digit of a Number

Tags: java, eclipse

I know that 2389 % 10 is 9, but how could I create a method that takes 2 parameters?  One for the number, and the other for the index and will return the value at index...

Comment: Pls see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19194257/return-the-nth-digit-of-a-number

Comment: For n'th digit counting by the right: divide by 10^(n-1) with / operator and then by 10 with % operator.

Comment: What does `2389` mean in mathematics? Are you familiar with the idea of "place values"? When you understand the mathematics behind representation of numbers, you should be able to do this pretty easily.

Comment: In your question, do you mean that "2" would be index 0, "3" would be index 1, etc.?

Answer (score 3):

You could do it using the `charAt()` method for a string:

```
public static int getNthDigit(int n, int pos) {
    return Character.getNumericValue(String.valueOf(n).charAt(pos))
}
```

**Be careful**: index start from 0. That means `getNthDigit(1234,2)` will return `3`

You could ensure the `pos` number is in range before looking for it:

```
public static int getNthDigit(int n, int pos) {
    String toStr = String.valueOf(n)
    if (pos >= toStr.length() || pos < 0) {
        System.err.println("Bad index")
        return -1
    }
    return Character.getNumericValue(toStr.charAt(pos))
}
```

Comment: It worked for me... Can you tell me what is your issue then? (give me the parameter you entered and result)

Comment: It is not letting me parse to an int for some reason.

Comment: Please give me the parameters you entered, and output you had

Comment: My question is: What value did you test your function against? For instance if I enter `getNthDigit(1234, 3)` I have a value of `4`.

Comment: I am testing the value 100 at pos 2.  I get an error when trying to parse.

Comment: Ok the error was because it was no string but character, i updated

Comment: Thank you, however when I test 100 with pos 3, it gives me an out of bounds error.

Comment: This was one of my questions for my Java class, but when I give it the value of 123456789 and pos 4, it does not return 4.  I need it to start on the right side.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a chat neither a code learning tool. Please have a **clear** question that indicates an error you encountered. To which I can answer. I’m not meant to guess your question, nor to talk with you in the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int getDigitAtIndex(int numberToExamine, int index) {
        if(index < 0) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        if(index == 0 && numberToExamine < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        String stringVersion = String.valueOf(numberToExamine);
        if(index >= stringVersion.length()) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        return Character.getNumericValue(stringVersion.charAt(index));
    }
```