# More efficient way to return a specific unit (as integer) inside a double?

Tags: java, int, double, indexof

I'm not searching for clean and good looking code.

I'm curious if there is a way to do it with less conversions and function calls

Explaining all passages

```
public static int Double (double d, int p) {
    String dToString = d+"";
    char stringToChar = dToString.charAt(p);
    String charToString = stringToChar+"";
    int stringToInt = Integer.parseInt(charToString);
    return stringToInt;
}
```

Condensed and ugly version

```
public static int Double (double d, int p) {
    return Integer.parseInt(((d+"").charAt(p))+"");
}
```

}

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19194257/return-the-nth-digit-of-a-number

Comment: You know that your second snippet will always throw `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`, right?

Comment: You could use `Character.getNumericValue(stringToChar)`

Comment: "condensed and ugly version" is different. I suspect you mean `return Integer.parseInt((d+"").charAt(p)+"");`. You could have used `return Integer.parseInt((d+"").substring(p, p+1));` alternatively, or `Double.toString(d).substring(...)` etc.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I didn't copy & paste and forgot the parentesis but yep, that's what I meant. I'll try the two other alternatives, thanks :)